# Gather Insagram Username using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, instagram

i'm trying to save usernames who liked my post in Instagram

here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import *
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CMAVjR5CmOx/')


continue_link = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('others')
continue_link.click()

elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".FPmhX.notranslate.MBL3Z")
links = [elem.get_attribute('title') for elem in elems]

WebElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[ contains (text(), ‘#’ ) ]')
WebElement.click()

browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebElement)
```

**the problem** is, it just save 11 first username and it can't scroll down to load all of them

i tried some codes to scroll down but it scroll main page while i want "followers list" to be scrolled

[main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp3j9.png)

can anyone help me with this scrolling down?

i tried for "send.key" and "browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",Element)" but nothing usefull

Comment: Was your question resolved?

Comment: @vitaliis no unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. I'm using it right now so pretty sure it work.

```
# try to find the locator of the div element which contain the slider
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div/parent::ul/parent::div')

# increase the distance from the top element each time one pixel
verical_ordinate = 100
for i in range(0, 50):
   print(verical_ordinate)
   browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]", element, 
   verical_ordinate)
   verical_ordinate += 100
   time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling, I usually use this code and it always works.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",driver.find_element_by_xpath("your_xpath_selector"))
```

First, rename `WebElement` to your custom name, for example to `web_element` as your name is confusing.
Second, make sure this locator is correct. Unfortunately, I do not have an Instagram account and cannot verify this locator.

Comment: if you don't have an instagram account, it's not a problem, you can see a public post and control its html tags. 
i know my main problem is, i can't find the correct element to scroll it. instgram has many classes to show a list

Comment: Please add html code in which you want to find a locator. I can help with that locator.

Comment: how can i send you its photo, give me an email or any social media account please

Comment: You can post a part of html code as a snippet here. Use devtools to find the part the you need.