# Python selenium scrolling down Instagram users likes

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9YSc.png

I want to scroll down this little window because I want to scrape all of the users who liked this post.
I tried `driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,925)", "")` but It doesn't work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Val5.jpg
Here's HTML. `_1XyCr` is the whole window class which I want to scroll down

Comment: Need more info. Can you find the users as webElements? What exactly are you trying to scrape?  Most importantly, what is the HTML for your page?

Comment: I want to scrape username. I've already done It  `elems =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z']")` I just want to scroll down this window, It's list of Instagram profiles which liked this post

Comment: Please share the full HTML or a link to the page for a full answer.

Comment: @Peck I added HTML

Comment: Using the `window.scrollBy` function scrolls the entire window, not the likes element which has a different scroll bar in the same window. This would require using the `scollIntoView` method to interact with any scrolls in any element inside the window. There's a similar question with a solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630999/16242139]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
#like list(whole pop-up) xpath = <div style="height: 356px ....">
like_list = driver.find_element_xpath("(like list xpath)")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", like_list)
```